# Nuance in the line ちゃんと活かしてきっちり役立てていきたいんです

Tags: nuances

It's as the topic states. A person is speaking about them wanting to put their ability to good use, and they say it as:

> (previous bit is less relevant) ちゃんと活かしてきっちり役立てていきたいんです

What I want to know, is nuance/difference between:
ちゃんと活かして
and 
きっちり役立てて

Because both pretty much say the same thing if I take their straight meaning from the dictionary.

ちゃんと活かして diligently/earnestly/perfectly/quickly make the best use

きっちり役立てて precisely/punctually/perfectly/properly make use/put to use.

The only large difference that there might be, that might necessitate using both when only one might suffice is that the first one seems to deal with regularity, saying that the person wants to help often, while the later seems to deal with quality of use.

So this would be

> I want to diligently make the best use of (whatever)

or does someone have a better explanation of the difference and better suggestion for translation?

Answer (score 2):

From Yahoo Japan 'Chiebukuro' (best answer)
「きちんと」は、 「整然と」「順序よく」という概念が強く、
「ちゃんと」は、「完全に」「間違わないで」という概念が強い というところが、その違いでしょう。

ちゃんと is concerned with 'doing it right', while きちんと is more concerned with the method and the order that are used to 'do it right'.

ちゃんと: Fully, completely, without fail

きちんと/きっちりと:  well, precisely, correctly; in proper order, neatly

Keep in mind that context is most important. In the example sentence, as the speaker likely doesn't want to sound redundant, they use two different words to signify the same meaning. **In this case, there really isn't much difference in meaning between the two words.**

My closest translation (highly paraphrased) of the example sentence would be: 'I want to make full use of my talents and commit to making a difference'.